# Find a symmetric matrix $B$ such that for every $3\times 1$ matrix $\text{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=$
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & -1\\
3 & 0 & 1\\
-2 & 5 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.$

Find a symmetric matrix $B$ such that for every $3\times1$ matrix $\text{x}$,

$$\text{x}^TA\text{x}=\text{x}^TB\text{x}$$

I've tried to take the inverse of $A$ and $\text{x}$ to cancel out, but I get nowhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: try $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for all $x$, we have
$$
x^TAx = x^TBx \implies\\
x^TAx - x^TBx = 0 \implies\\
x^T(A - B)x = 0
$$
What can we say, then, about $A-B$?

Answer (score 0):

A way to naively discover the answer. I will do this generally for a $3\times3$ matrix, perhaps you will get an idea of how to generalise it.

Given scalars $a_{ij}$ we want to find $b_{ij}$ such that for all $3\times1$ column vectors $x$:

$$x^T\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}x=x^T\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\end{pmatrix}x$$

and such that $b_{ij}=b_{ji}$

Now we just make some useful choices for $x$. If you let $x=e_1,e_2,e_3$, the equation reduces to showing the diagonal elements are equal.

If you pick
$$x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

then the equation becomes

$$a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{21}+a_{22}=b_{11}+b_{12}+b_{21}+b_{22}$$

Since the diagonal elements are equal, and $b_{12}=b_{21}$, this implies that

$$b_{12}=b_{21}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{12}+a_{22})$$

Similarly, you can choose

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

and deduce that $b_{13}=b_{31}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{13}+a_{31})$ and $b_{23}=b_{32}=\frac{1}{2}(a_{23}+a_{32})$ respectively. This forces $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ (and note $B$ is clearly symmetric).

Finally, you just need to verify that $B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ actually works, and this is not so hard.